# PyCuda 1D interpolation using texture 1D

Tags: python, cuda, textures, pycuda

I'm new to CUDA and my goal is to implement a simple 1D interpolation using PyCUDA and CUDA 1D textures. For testing purpose I just want a kernel which returns me the original image values (extracted from the texture) in an array. the problem is that `tex1D(tex, pos);` returns always 0.

This is my CUDA kernel code:

```
interp1 = """

#include <stdint.h>

texture<uint8_t, 1> tex;


__global__ 
void interp1(uint8_t *out) {

    unsigned int pos = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    out[pos] = tex1D(tex, pos);
}

"""
```

And this is my python code snipped, where I read in an test image, allocate memory on the GPU, copy the image onto the GPU, create my texture reference via `set_address` and call my kernel:

```
...
img = cv2.imread("lena.jpg", 0)    
img_in = pycuda.driver.to_device(img.flatten())
texref.set_address(img_in, img.nbytes)
texref.set_format(pycuda.driver.array_format.UNSIGNED_INT8, 1)

img_out = pycuda.driver.mem_alloc(img.nbytes)

interp1_func(img_out, block=(512, 1, 1), grid=(7200, 1, 1)) # image is 1920 x 1920

context.synchronize()
imgnew = np.zeros_like(img.flatten())
pycuda.driver.memcpy_dtoh(imgnew, img_out)
imgnew = imgnew.reshape(img.shape)
...
```

I hope someone can help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have bound linear memory to the texture reference, you must use [`tex1Dfetch`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#tex1dfetch-object), rather than [`tex1D`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#tex1d-object) within the kernel to access the texture.

Note that in this case, it also is not possible to perform interpolation, only lookups.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I understand... But what do I then have to do to be able to perform the 1D interpolation?

Comment: @Phil: You would need to set up a texture array and bind that (and use tex1D with a normalised coordinate system) if you want to perform filtering (interpolation)